# Что хуже? Лишняя переменная или лишние вычисления?

Tags: движок

Сегодня вечером решал задачки по программированию и задался вопросом.
У меня есть функция, которая в определенных моментах должна высчитывать одно и тоже (например, (JavaScript -->) `Math.sqrt(myVar)`, `myArr[i][key]`). Также я знаю, что значение вычисления никогда не поменяется. Так вот. Есть ли смысл создавать новые переменные, высчитывая один раз, или будет лучше несколько раз заставлять высчитывать Движок одно и тоже?

Comment: Зависит от частоты вызова. Нужно понять баланс между памятью и процессорным временем

Comment: переменная лучше конечно же. вычисления будут больше места занимать

Comment: Сильно зависит от вашего алгоритма и используемого компилятора. Вполне может быть, что компилятор сам на этапе оптимизации вставит сохранение ваших вычисления в какую-нибудь временную переменную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кешировать значения - это нормальная практика. Во многих языках для этого есть уже готовые структуры.

В той же Java есть [`Cache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html), который инвалидирует старые значения, когда они уже не нужны. В наше время память куда дешевле процессорных мощностей. Поэтому, если стоит выбор между cpu/RAM, то я всегда выбираю ускорение алгоритма, при этом использовав побольше памяти.

Но, опять же:

> Premature optimization really the root of all evil

Об этих вещах нужно думать только в случае реальных проблем с производительностью.

Comment: Только надо всегда помнить, что random доступ к L2 это пара десятков тактов, а к L3 уже сотня. Также стоит иметь в виду, что при последовательном доступе к данным процессор (точнее аппаратура кэша) будет пытаться делать предвыборку, что сильно сглаживает первоначально печальную картину

Comment: @avp зависит от того, что мы там храним )

Comment: Я лишь дал примерные ориентиры для прикидок, не будет ли вычисление всегда быстрее хранения

Comment: *We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.*